# In CEX.IO Should I include the fee in the sending bitcoin amount?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, withdrawal, cex.io

I'm using CEX.IO and I want to do a purchase in usi-tech with bitcoin. In this case I need to send the exact amount that they are asking to usi-tech from CEX.IO. When I'm going to enter the amount to withdraw from CEX.IO do I need to include the transaction fee also into the amount that I'm entering.

i.e If usi-tech asks me to pay 0.015 BTC and since the transaction fee of CEX.IO is 0.001 BTC. Do I need to enter 0.016 BTC to the amount field or just 0.015 BTC for the purchasing site to identify the transaction?

[image]

Please ignore the red message in the above image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending a transaction to a recipient, they generally don't care what fees have been paid; they just care how much they've received at their given receiving address.

If you're wanting to send 0.015BTC then you'll need to ensure the fees don't reduce that amount. Given the screenshot, it is reasonably clear that you'd need to enter 0.016BTC to ensure that 0.015BTC arrives at the receiving address.